# Matrices- Is this relationship transitive?

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, relations

Let $Z$ be the set $\{1,2,3\}$ Then the relation $R: \{(1,1) (2,2) (3,3) (3,1) (3,2) (1,3) (1,2)\}$ is transitive? How to represent matrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is transitive.

The usual way to represent the relation using a matrix would be to take the $3 \times 3$ matrix with entries $1$ corresponding to $(i,j)$ in the relation and $0$ otherwise.

$$ M = \pmatrix{1 & 1 & 1\cr 0 & 1 & 0\cr 1 & 1 & 1\cr}$$

Transitivity corresponds to the fact that $M^2 \ge M$.

Comment: Thanks! would be (3,1), (1,2) ∈ R , is transitive because (3, 2) ∈ R?

Comment: For $R$ to be transitive, you need $(x,z) \in R$ **whenever** $(x,y) \in R$ and $(y,z) \in R$.  The one you quoted is one of the cases ($x=3,y=1,z=2$), but there are others.